# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement for my own module

Tags: python, pip

I have a Python module which I published to Pip, but I'm having a hard time installing it myself and I'm not really sure why.

Below is the error I'm getting, even though `1.0.3` is indeed published on the registry: https://pypi.org/project/Discord-Webhooks/

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Discord-Webhooks==1.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Discord-Webhooks==1.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

This is what my `setup.py` file looks like. Running `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` produces no errros when building the project.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

long_description = open('README.md').read()

setup(
  name='Discord Webhooks',
  version='1.0.3',
  py_modules=['discord_webhooks'],
  url='https://github.com/JamesIves/discord-webhooks',
  author='James Ives',
  author_email='email@email.com',
  description='Easy to use package for Python which allows for sending of webhooks to a Discord server.',
  long_description=long_description,
  license='MIT',
  install_requires=[
    'requests==2.21.0'
  ],
  classifiers=[
    'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
    'Environment :: Other Environment',
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
  ],
)
```

Am I missing something here? How come I can't run `pip install Discord-Webhooks` without an error? I'm running `Python 3.6.0`.

Comment: Try `pip3 install Discord-Webhooks`

Comment: This is no surprise since you have uploaded the wheel installable by Python 2 only:[`Discord_Webhooks-1.0.3-py2-none-any.whl`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/08/e366ba25f98257b612e7c1567692afac859f104416bf459334ffb67b1c5b/Discord_Webhooks-1.0.3-py2-none-any.whl) can't be installed by Python 3 (missing `py3` in the interpreter tag). You can either build and upload a Python 3 wheel, or upload a universal wheel (`python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --universal`), or upload a source distribution. Of course, check first if your project supports both Python 2 and 3, adapt the code if necessary.

Comment: Appreciate the information @hoefling - this ended up solving the issue for me. If you post a reply I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have uploaded a wheel built with Python 2, this is indicated by the python tag `py2` in the wheel name: [`Discord_Webhooks-1.0.3-py2-none-any.whl`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/08/e366ba25f98257b612e7c1567692afac859f104416bf459334ffb67b1c5b/Discord_Webhooks-1.0.3-py2-none-any.whl). You need to upload a wheel built using Python 3:

```
$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

You can also specify the tag explicitly:

```
$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --python-tag=py3
```

then you can also build the `py3` wheel using Python 2 (of course if the setup script doesn't use any incompatible code). Another possibility, if your code runs with both Python 2 and 3, is to build a universal wheel:

```
$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
```

This will produce a wheel with the python tag `py2.py3`, which is installable with both Python major versions.